# Como otimizar a velocidade do insert Mysql?

Tags: mysql

Criei uma tabela para teste e adicionei um script que gera caracteres aleatoriamente e da um insert nos campos a, b e c.
Para a realização de 1000 INSERTS levou o tempo de 36s e rodando o mesmo script porém sem gravar no banco o resultado foi de 1 segundo. Consigo melhorar esse tempo de alguma forma?

**Configuração:**

Tipo de servidor: *MariaDB*
Sistema Operacional: *Windows 7*
RAM: *4G*

Processador: *Pentium E5700 3Ghz*

**Banco:**

```
CREATE TABLE `teste` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `a` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `c` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) 
ALTER TABLE `teste`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
ALTER TABLE `teste`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi seu script gera um comando INSERT para cada tupla a ser incluída. Tente juntar múltiplas tuplas em um único comando INSERT. Avalie também se o uso do comando LOAD DATA não agiliza sua carga.

Answer (score 1):

Eu altero essas diretivas no mysql para melhorar a performance e velocidade de todo o funcionamento do meu mysql. Pode ser que seja útil pra vc.

Procure pelo seu arquivo my.ini e altere essas configurações:

Pesquisar por: [mysqld]

```
[mysqld]    

skip-name-resolve #acrescente esta linha
```

Altere todos os valores abaixo significantemente:

```
key_buffer = 1024M
max_allowed_packet = 1024M
sort_buffer_size = 2048M
net_buffer_length = 500K
read_buffer_size = 2048M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2048M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1024M
```

E o mais importante nisto tudo é você criar **índices** na sua tabela.

No banco de dados MySQL os índices podem ser criados com considerável facilidade, tanto no momento da concepção da tabela quanto em uma tabela já existente.

```
CREATE TABLE CLIENTES
(
    Codigo  INT,
    Nome    VARCHAR(50),
    INDEX (Codigo)
);
```

Aqui você nota que o `index` foi criado no campo **código**.

Comment: Leandro, pode explicar o que fazem essas configurações e como elas melhoram a performance do insert?

Comment: @RicardoPontual as diretivas acima não melhora somente insert, mas sim o ganho de performance de pelo menos 30% de desempenho em todas as consultas, insert, update. Ou seja desempenho do mysql em si. Por experiência própria, pois você aumenta, principalmente, o uso da memória principal para auxiliar a execução do mysql. Mas o grande ganho de performance. COM TODA CERTEZA, é o uso de index. Depois que otimizamos nossas tabelas com index ganhamos um desempenho de pelo menos 60%.

Comment: Leandro, uma tabela sem index insere muito, muito mais rápido que uma tabela com index, acho que tem um mal entendido ai... o index vai melhor a performance na consulta, no select... um index faz com que o motor do banco, além de inserir dados e gerenciar a paginação, tenha de atualizar o índice, e ainda mais, validar as constraints, a forma como explicou não me parece correta

Comment: @RicardoPontual Te entendo, mas a performance de meus clientes (+200) melhoraram e MUITO. O uso do processador caiu para 2%. Enfim, utilizo essas configurações em todos meus servidores e o ganho é visivelmente ótimo. Acredito que a prática + experiência de uso seja mais útil que teoria.

Comment: sobre as configurações não posso opinar pois não conheço a maioria, mas gostaria de saber mais concretamente como cada uma influencia na performace, mas dos poucos que conheço, como read e sort buffer impactam nas consultas, por isso fiquei curioso para saber como elas impactam nos inserts tb, seria legal falar mais delas, tunning é sempre bom :)

Comment: E quanto seria aumentar significativamente? Poderia dar um exemplo?

Comment: Leandro, a questão não é as configurações, mas essa afirmação na sua pergunta: *"E o mais importante nisto tudo é você criar índices na sua tabela"*, como disse antes, para o que perguntado, para insert, isso não garante melhora na performance, pelo contrário, apenas isso